# Hybris - ImpEx update using [batchmode =true]

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Please give me an example about ImpEx update using `[batchmode =true]` and without using `[batchmode =true]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's take as example these two items :

Product 1 :

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    | id (unique) | catalog (unique)       | name    |                  
    --------------------------------------------------
    |  x          | staged                 |         |
    --------------------------------------------------
```

Product 2 :

```
    --------------------------------------------------
    | id (unique) | catalog (unique)       | name    |                  
    --------------------------------------------------
    |  x          | online                 |         |
    --------------------------------------------------
```

And let's assume that here you want to update the name of both of the items using an impex :

**BATCH MODE :**

Using batch mode it will be (minimum one unqiue attribute needed to modify items, and it modifies all the items that matches that unique attribute, non unique attribute will be updated)  :

```
UPDATE Product[batchmode=true]; id[unique]; name;
                                     ; x         ; randomName;
```

**WITHOUT BATCH MODE :**

Without batch mode you have to specify all the unique attribute to modify the items:

```
UPDATE Product; id[unique]; catalog[unique=true]; name;
                     ; x       ; staged              ; randomName;
                     ; x       ; online              ; randomName;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @DoNguyen The product have `id` unique and also `catalog` unique, so this is allowed since they dont have both the same values on all unique attribute

Answer (score 0):

Without batch mode you have to specify a unique attribute (or set of attributes for each row). Each row MUST have a unique set of primary key i.e. attributes with `[unique=true]`.

With batch mode you can create a row without specifying unique attributes i.e. the attribute specified as `[unique=true]` can be present in multiple rows in the database.